# Uploaded media url is incorrect (custom absolute path is used instead of relative)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some problem with my WordPress 5.2.3 website since yesterday. When I (or someone else) upload a media, the generated URL is incorrect, so I can't see the media.

I was simply writing an article yesterday, and everything was still working fine, I managed to upload multiple images like usual and insert them in my article, and suddenly when I tried to upload another image, it "broke" and didn't shown correctly.

I thought that it was in the name of my image, so I renamed it, but I still had the same problem.

I use a custom `UPLOADS` folder named "medias". It is defined in my `wp-config.php` as below. When I commented this line, the media upload worked again, but my images were not in the folder (so, not accessible through the url) I wanted...

```php
define('UPLOADS', 'medias');
```

In fact, what my WordPress generated for my uploaded media is a link with my website followed by the absolute path of my custom `UPLOADS` folder... Like this:

```
https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads//home/user/public_html/medias/2019/09/asm_icon.png
```

When I visit what should be the correct url (so, `https://www.website.com/medias/2019/09/asm_icon.png`), it correctly shows me the image I uploaded, so it means that the upload works fine but that the returned URL is incorrect...

Have you ever experienced this issue? I don't know what to do... Everything was working fine until yesterday. :( I didn't do nothing special, like an update or whatever...

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**: I figured out what was the problem... My custom variable was defined after the `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );` line. After placing it before, everything surprisingly worked normally again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem... My custom variable was defined after the `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );` line. After placing it before, everything surprisingly worked normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder name is media, and you are using medias here. Change it to

```
define('UPLOADS', 'media');
```

Moreover, `https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads//home/user/public_html/medias/2019/09/asm_icon.png` is wrong there must be single slash after uploads. You have put // after uploads.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a mistake during the writing of my problem, the name is "medias". I know that there must not be two "/", but I can't fix that, that is why I posted a question here. :/